# TextField accept just certain count of numbers in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a field for number phone and I want it to accept just numbers and the user can type just a 10 numbers

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation#2-add-a-textformfield-with-validation-logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a TextField or a TextFormField with `keyboardType: TextInputType.phone` and `inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)]`